# Show Event Log XML parameters in PowerShell script

Tags: xml, powershell, event-viewer

I have a PowerShell script that gets the logon history for RDP connections from Event Viewer, then puts it in a CSV file. I want to include the Correlation ActivityID in the table, which I can see in the XML view.

[Screenshot of the event log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M1i3.png)

```
Param(
[array]$ServersToQuery = (hostname),
[datetime]$StartTime = "January 1, 1970"
)

foreach ($Server in $ServersToQuery) {

    $LogFilter = @{
        LogName = 'Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational'
        ID = 21, 23, 24, 25
        StartTime = $StartTime
        }

    $AllEntries = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $LogFilter -ComputerName $Server

    $AllEntries | Foreach { 
        $entry = [xml]$_.ToXml()
        [array]$Output += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            TimeCreated = $_.TimeCreated
            User = $entry.Event.UserData.EventXML.User
            IPAddress = $entry.Event.UserData.EventXML.Address
            EventID = $entry.Event.System.EventID
            ServerName = $Server
            }        
        } 

}

$FilteredOutput += $Output | Select TimeCreated, User, ServerName, IPAddress, @{Name='Action';Expression={
            if ($_.EventID -eq '21'){"logon"}
            if ($_.EventID -eq '22'){"Shell start"}
            if ($_.EventID -eq '23'){"logoff"}
            if ($_.EventID -eq '24'){"disconnected"}
            if ($_.EventID -eq '25'){"reconnection"}
            }
        }

$Date = (Get-Date -Format s) -replace ":", "."
$FilePath = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\$Date`_RDP_Report.csv"
$FilteredOutput | Sort TimeCreated | Export-Csv $FilePath -NoTypeInformation

Write-host "Writing File: $FilePath" -ForegroundColor Cyan
Write-host "Done!" -ForegroundColor Cyan
```

Any ideas how I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can dot-index the same way you have for the other values:

```
[array]$Output += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    TimeCreated = $_.TimeCreated
    ActivityID  = $entry.Event.System.Correlation.ActivityID     # here
    User        = $entry.Event.UserData.EventXML.User
    IPAddress   = $entry.Event.UserData.EventXML.Address
    EventID     = $entry.Event.System.EventID
    ServerName  = $Server
}
```

Comment: This doesn't return anything, just , , in the CSV.

Comment: @dynmatt The issue isn't with the new line... if your original code was working, the worst that should happen is you get a blank `ActivityID` field. Can you post an example xml and current output? PS You'll need to update the `Select` to include the `ActivityID` field for it to be in the final output.